# CXF client - how to set SoapVersion on CXF port without Spring

Tags: java, soap, cxf, soap-client, cxf-client

I am consuming a soap 1.2 wsdl with springboot and CXF, however the request I am sending is being geneated with SOAP 1.1 namespace. I am running into soap fault.

I am looking for a way to send a request with soap 1.2 envelope.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.